# What does this React error mean? "Expected onBeforeMountComponent() parent and onSetChildren() to be consistent"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Using Material UI with this example React component:

```
const React = require('react');
const DropDownMenu = require('material-ui/DropDownMenu').default;
const MenuItem = require('material-ui/MenuItem').default;

const MyDropDown = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            onChange: () => {},
            items: []
        };
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            value: undefined
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        const {
            state: {value},
            props: {items, id}
        } = this;

        return React.createElement(DropDownMenu, {
            id,
            maxHeight: 300,
            onChange: (event, index, value) => {
                this.setState({value});
            },
            value: typeof value === 'undefined'
                    ? items[0].value
                    : value,
            children: items.map((item, key) => (
                React.createElement(MenuItem, {
                    value: item.value,
                    primaryText: item.label,
                    key
                })
            ))
        });
    }
});
```

When I select or hover one of the items, I get this error.

```
Exception thrown by hook while handling onSetChildren:
Invariant Violation: Expected onBeforeMountComponent() parent
and onSetChildren() to be consistent (74 has parents 41 and 73).
```

This reproduces across any Material UI component with clickable children.
The reading material for the error is frustratingly sparse. **What does this error mean, and why is it happening?**

Comment: Didn't know const keyword worked on ES5 ^^

Comment: @Mayday Thanks for catching that. Removed mention of ES5. I should have said it was closer TO ES5 than ES6.

Comment: Are you passing some props to MyDropDown component? Since otherwise, it takes default items = empty array, default value = undefined, and then you try to get items[0].value which might result in a null pointer (Not sure if it's related to the problem you see)

Comment: Did you check the OnChange function? the set of state seems to be wrong. It's missing the variable

Comment: @damianfabian @Mayday The use of state is based on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu, and in my case `this.props.items` is populated. You can assume the props are correct.

Comment: @damianfabian If this were true ES5, yes. But the transpiler understands this as `this.setState({ value: value });`

Comment: just FYI https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8692